# Support for using >2TB HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, sata, gpt

Iam working on providing support for HDD morethan 2TB on TI8107 board. According to GPT header, at LBA1 with offset of 0x28 we get the first usable sector and LBA1 with offset of 0x30 we get the last usable sector/LBA. In case of HDD lessthan 2TB, iam getting the correct number of last usable sector/LBA but in case of HDD >2TB, the value present at LBA1 offset 0x30 is different from that of actual total number of sectors. Verified using hexdump of the HDD.

Ex: For 4TB HDD, The total number of sectors are : 7814037168 (which is 3.63TB ) But the value read at LBA1 offset 0x30 is : 3519069838 (which is 1.63TB). Total size is 3.63TB but when read from header it shows 1.63TB (which is 3.63TB - 2TB).

Why is it showing the leftover memory after 2TB ? How can i read the actual number of sectors for HDD >2TB.

For 6TB :

output of df -h :

```
root@dm814x-evm:~# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used    Available Use% Mounted on�
/dev/sda1                 1.5T      207.5M  1.4T      0%   /media/hdd1-vid
```

output of gdisk /dev/sda :

```
root@dm814x-evm:~# gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 11721045168 sectors, 5.5 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2156215D-E245-46E0-8F4D-1E35C3B227A2
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 11721045134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 6108 sectors (3.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      4194304000   2.0 TiB     8300  Linux filesystem
   2      4194306048      8388608000   2.0 TiB     8300  Linux filesystem
   3      8388610048     11721045134   1.6 TiB     8300  Linux filesystem

Command (? for help):
```

Comment: What device is this for? Only this I found close to TI8107 was a "DM8107DVRRD (Development Kits)" by Texas Instruments. Is this what you are working on? Also, what file system is on the hard drive? Ext2, 3, 5, ntfs, something proprietary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main body of your question refers to a 4TB disk, but your `gdisk` output shows a 6TB disk. I see no problem with the `gdisk` output, unless the disk was really a 4TB model. If you're having problems with your 4TB disk, please show the `gdisk` output from it. (Also, add four spaces to the start of each line of output to preserve columnar formatting. I've edited your question to add that for your `gdisk` and `df` output.) Go back and edit your question with the new output, if necessary.

It's possible that you're simply misinterpreting the GPT data structures. Remember that GPT pointers are 64 bits (8 bytes) in size, not the 32-bit (4-byte) pointers of MBR. Using `gdisk` or some other well-tested partitioning software to interpret your data structures will greatly reduce the chances of human error in interpreting those pointers. Using the `v` option in `gdisk` to check the GPT data structures for sanity is worth doing if you suspect problems. This command will produce a report on any problems `gdisk` finds.

Another possibility is that you've got a driver with a 32-bit limitation. This is common with Windows, and especially with 32-bit Windows. Such drivers often truncate the 64-bit pointers to 32-bit, which usually results in a disk seeming to "lose" 2TiB of space (or 4TiB for over-4TiB disks, or theoretically higher values still for even bigger disks). If you run into this problem, the solution is to replace the buggy driver with a non-buggy driver. In some cases, disk repairs will be necessary, if data were written to the disk while the buggy driver was in use.

One final comment: Do not confuse terabytes (TB, 1000^4 bytes) with tebibytes (TiB, 1024^4 bytes), or equivalents for other prefixes (GB-vs-GiB, etc.). You seem to be using "TB" to refer to both units of measure. This was common practice a decade or more ago, but as disk sizes have increased, it's becoming more and more confusing. See [this page](http://stopabusingsiprefixes.org/stopabusing.html) for more on this topic.

Comment: Hi Rod Smith,

Thank you for taking time and providing me a solution. I was reading 8bytes of data but because of missing type-casting of (unsigned long long int) I was getting lower 4Bytes correctly with corrupted upper 4Bytes. Thnk you again for giving extra information.